# In C#, How do I call a function that is returning a list?

Tags: c#, list, function, methods

In C#, How do I call a function that is returning a list?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  
        List<string> range = new List<string>();  
        range.ForEach(item => item.WildcardFiles());  //this is not working             
    }  

    List<string> WildcardFiles(string first)  
    {  
        List<string> listRange = new List<string>();  
        listRange.Add("q");  
        listRange.Add("s");  

        return listRange;  
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Just calling a method is fine, but what are you trying to *do* with the results? You're currently calling `ForEach` on an empty list in Main...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are various things wrong with your code:

- You're creating an empty list, and then calling `ForEach` on it. That's not going to do anything.
- You're trying to call `WildcardFiles` on a string, when it's not a method of string.
- You're trying to call `WildcardFiles` which is an instance method in whatever your declaring type is, but without any instances of that type.
- You're trying to call `WildcardFiles` without passing in an argument for the `first` parameter
- You're ignoring the return value of the call to `WildcardFiles`
- `WildcardFiles` ignores its parameter

Now I *suspect* you really wanted something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{  
    List<string> range = WildcardFiles();
    foreach (string item in range)
    {
        // Do something with item
    }
}  

static List<string> WildcardFiles()
{  
    List<string> listRange = new List<string>();  
    listRange.Add("q");  
    listRange.Add("s");  

    return listRange;  
}
```

Comment: It looked to me like he wanted to do a `SelectMany` type of thing. Your idea looks like a possibility too, though.

Comment: The compiler is not accepting this line:   List<string> range = WildcardFiles();

Comment: @CN: It should - I've just compiled it on my machine. You need a `using` directive for `System.Collections.Generic` though. What error message are you getting?

Comment: @Jon Skeet - The error message is: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MethodReturnList.Program.WildcardFiles()'"  I do currently have the directive System.Collection.Generic

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes, it worked, after I changed WildcardFiles to static.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what exactly you want but currently you should do:

```
range.ForEach(item => WildcardFiles(item));
```

and make your method static to work.

Comment: @Kyle Trauberman why instance? as I wrote we should have an static method, before downvoting test what I said and then tell me what is wrong.

Comment: There's more to it than this. Presumably one would want to do something with the list returned by `WildcardFiles()`.

Comment: I missed your last sentence.  Sorry.  I removed the downvote.

Comment: @David Heffernan, really I don't know what's the thing OP want's I just address title by OPs code, may be it's crazy, but first as Jon commented should be cleared what's the thing OP wants then we can refactor it.

Comment: @Saeed Amiri Agree with you 100%. David, presumably you but it wasn't the question.

Comment: +1 This answers the users question...even if I did beat you to it lol Cheers!

Comment: @Saeed Amiri Thanks, I'll update the post was really only paying attention to the question itself could have left out the rest.